# nginx - Wildcard domain force www

Tags: nginx

I know I can redirect a non-www from a specific domain to a www version by doing:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name domain.com;
  return 301 $scheme://www.domain.com$request_uri;
}
```

But what if I want to catch any domain that does not have a subdomain already set (like `help.domain.com`) to redirect to `www`, like `newdomain.com` redirecting to `www.newdomain.com`. The trick here is I want to catch any domain pointed towards the server, not ones that I "know of"

Comment: http://serverfault.com/q/708709/211028